# How to improve baseline logistic regression in a high dimensional binary classification problem?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression

Info about dataset:

- `df.shape = (10000, 100)`
- All feature are numerical values.
- There are few outliers in each column. The column with the most outliers has 0.7% of data as outliers.

I am trying to improve on my baseline logistic regression; however, I'm stuck.

```
baseline = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', max_iter=100, penalty='l2')
```

Here are some approaches I've taken and relative results:

1. Standard scaler - Logistic regression (similar)
2. Robust scaler - Logistic regression (simliar)
3. Remove outliers (IQR method) - standard scaler - Logistic regression (worse)
4. Standard scaler - PCA (n_component=n_comp that explain 83% variance) - Logistic regression (more worse)

All approaches seem to perform worse than the baseline.

How can I improve my baseline logistic regression model or do I need to resort to nonlinear models like random forest (I've already tried it however it overfits)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried regularization ? Perhaps try lasso regression since that has the effect of eliminating features that are essentially noise to your problem objective.

Comment: Are you able to share a sample of your data? So that I can work out with it? at least 500 observations randomly sampled would be enough

Comment: @JayaramIyer So simply changing logistic regression paramater "penalty=l1" would do?

Comment: Use penalty = l1, solver = saga and C = 0.1 (reducing the value increases the amount of regularization applied)

Comment: @JayaramIyer Thanks, indeed using lasso, c=0.1 but with solver="liblinear" improved performance and converged.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are using manual trial-and-error to search for better hyperparameters.

Another approach would to be use automated hyperparameter search. Define a search space (i.e., either a range or distribution) for each hyperparameter. Then use cross-validation to find the best combination in the search space. [Random search](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) on hyperparameters is often useful.